# Read google calendar events

Tags: node.js, express, request, google-calendar-api

I want to read the events of a public google calendar without Oauth authentication. 
But i can't get a response:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));


app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});




app.post("/", function(req,res){
  request("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/XXXXXXXXXXXX.calendar.google.com/events",function(response){

        var calendarSummary = response.summary;
        var calendarDescription =response.description;

        console.log("Response is:");
        console.log("Result is: "+calendarSummary+calendarDescription);
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("server is running on port 3000");
});
```

Any suggestions? Do i need to include an API-key for a public calendar?

Comment: I also tried with adding "?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]" to the request URL,but i don't get the calendar description/summary returned from Google.

I changed YOUR_API_KEY with a key in my google developers account (https://console.developers.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your usage of the `request` library/function.  Per [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) The signature for that function is `request(error, response, body)`, but you only supply one argument.  Despite calling it `response`, it's actually the `error` object which is probably `null`.  So, change it to the following and I bet it'll work:

```js
request("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/XXXXXXXXXXXX.calendar.google.com/events", function(error, response, body) {
  var calendarSummary = body.summary;
  var calendarDescription = body.description;
  console.log("Response is:");
  console.log("Result is: " + calendarSummary + calendarDescription);
});
```

I think your API call to Google is fine as-is because [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) says no authorization is needed.

Comment: I tried the above solution but don't get the calendar description + summary back from google.
The response in the terminal is: undefinedundifened.